# Using Json payload for RESTFul web services

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

I am new to using Json payload to call the Restful web services using Spring in Java. I know that XML can be marshaled into java objects and vice verse using XJC compiler and JAXB. But when I use json as the input payload, how will the json data be marshalled into Java object? Please let me know also if json is the most preferred way for data exchange that XML.

Comment: Are you just asking what is the equivalent of JAXB  for JSON? The usual default is Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), but as always, alternative marshallers are available. Whether to use JSON or XML is a matter of taste, although these days, I suspect the majority would go with JSON for REST.

Comment: In JAXB we have an xml schema as a contract. Similarly what is the schema equivalent when using jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json is faster and used to have better performance than xml, but on the other hand, xml has the metadata validation (xsd) and json doesn't